# tkinter Listbox item binding

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, bind

I'm trying to show a context menu when an item in a Listbox widget is right clicked.
The problem is that if a bind to the listbox, the whole Listbox will be active for send the event and it doesn't seem possible to bind to the list items only. I can't use `<<ListboxSelect>>` because it will be trigged on left click. So I tried to use the methods `curselection()` but I fell into unwanted results (the right clicked item doesn't have to be selected). I think I need to simulate `<<ListboxSelect>>` using `generate_event()` and `nearest()`. Can someone tell me how to do that or maybe where can i found the defaults binding inside tkinter package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `nearest(event.y)`. Bind to right-click and popup the menu when the callback is invoked.

```
import Tkinter

def context_menu(event, menu):
    widget = event.widget
    index = widget.nearest(event.y)
    _, yoffset, _, height = widget.bbox(index)
    if event.y > height + yoffset + 5: # XXX 5 is a niceness factor :)
        # Outside of widget.
        return
    item = widget.get(index)
    print "Do something with", index, item
    menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
aqua = root.tk.call('tk', 'windowingsystem') == 'aqua'

menu = Tkinter.Menu()
menu.add_command(label=u'hi')

listbox = Tkinter.Listbox()
listbox.insert(0, *range(1, 10, 2))
listbox.bind('<2>' if aqua else '<3>', lambda e: context_menu(e, menu))
listbox.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The menu will be posted also if you click in a blank space. There must be a way to show it only on item clicks. How does `<<ListboxSelect>>` work? It is possible to overload it ?

Comment: The blank space you are referring pertains to the listbox, so that is expected. You could simply set the `Listbox`'s height to the number of items it has: `listbox = Tkinter.Listbox(height=5)`. You cannot "overload" the event you are after, it is also irrelevant since you want to show a popup menu without the user left clicking an item.

Comment: Ok, I've never thought to change the height. Thank you.

Comment: @Rnhmjoj the updated answer doesn't rely on modifying the height, by the way.